# Searching in Excel with PHP

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I am trying to find the last cells value of a row in an Excel table by the first cells value using PHPExcel. The user enters the value of the first cell in the row (which is the "command" parameter) and if it exists in the table my function is supposed to jump to the last cell of the row and return the value. This is my code:

```
public function search($command, $excelobj) {
    foreach ($excelobj->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
        foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
            $rowiterator = $worksheet->getRowIterator();
            foreach ($row->getCellIterator() as $cell) {
                $celliterator = $row->getCellIterator();
                $head = $celliterator->current()->getValue();
                if(strcmp($head, $command)) {
                    for ($i = 0; $i == 8; $i++) {
                        $celliterator->next();
                    }
                    return $cell->getValue();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

For some reason it always returns wrong.

Comment: quick note: this function is a very bad code design example as it simply returns found value or nothing at all. You should return i.e. `false` or `null` or throw exception instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself, this code functions correctly:

```
public function search($command, $excelobj) {
    foreach ($excelobj->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
        foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
            $rowiterator = $worksheet->getRowIterator();
            $celliterator = $row->getCellIterator();
            $celliterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(true);
            $head = $celliterator->current()->getValue();
            while (strcmp($head, $command) !== 0 && $rowiterator->valid()) {
                $rowiterator->next();
                $row = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Row($worksheet, $rowiterator->key());
                $celliterator = $row->getCellIterator();
                $head = $celliterator->current()->getValue();
            }
            for ($i = 0; $i <= 7; $i++) {
                $celliterator->next();
            }
            return $celliterator->current()->getValue();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```